# Add user to private channel with aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

How to add user in private channel using aiogram?

I try `await bot.send_chat_action`, chatgpt send me this command, but it doesn't work. I have private channel in telegram and I need to add user in channel, when he write to bot command /channel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with AIOgram since this feature is not supported by the Telegram Bot API. These kinds of tasks can be accomplished using MTProto clients such as [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org) or [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/).

`bot.send_chat_action` is used to provide visual cues such as the sender "typing" or "sending photo" and so on.